# How to check whether a CGPoint is inside a UIImageView?

Tags: iphone

In `touchesBegan:`

```
CGPoint touch_point = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view];
```

There are tens of `UIImageView` around, stored in a `NSMutableArray` `images`. I'd like to know is there a built-in function to check if a `CGPoint` (touch_point) is inside one of the images, e.g.:

```
for (UIImageView *image in images) {
   // how to test if touch_point is tapped on a image?
}
```

Thanks

Follow up:

For unknown reason, `pointInside` never returns true. Here is the full code.

```
    - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
    { 
      UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject]; 
        touch_point = [touch locationInView:self.view];
        for (UIImageView *image in piece_images) {
            if ([image pointInside:touch_point withEvent:event]) {
                image.hidden = YES;
            } else {
                image.hidden = NO;
            }
            NSLog(@"image %.0f %.0f touch %.0f %.0f", image.center.x, image.center.y, touch_point.x, touch_point.y);
        }
    }
```

although I can see the two points are sometimes identical in the `NSLog` output.

I also tried:

```
  if ([image pointInside:touch_point withEvent:nil])
```

the result is the same. never returns a true.

To eliminate the chance of anything goes with with the images. I tried the following:

```
  if (YES or [image pointInside:touch_point withEvent:event])
```

all images are hidden after the first click on screen.

EDIT 2:

Really weird. Even I hard coded this:

```
        point.x = image.center.x;
        point.y = image.center.y;
```

the code becomes:

```
    - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
    { 
        UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject]; 
        CGPoint point; // = [touch locationInView:self.view];
        for (UIImageView *image in piece_images) {
            point.x = image.center.x;
            point.y = image.center.y;       
            if ([image pointInside:point withEvent:event]) {
                image.hidden = YES;
                NSLog(@"YES");
            } else {
                image.hidden = NO;
                NSLog(@"NO");
            }
            NSLog(@"image %.0f %.0f touch %.0f %.0f", image.center.x, image.center.y, point.x, point.y);
        }
    }
```

`pointInside` always returns `false` ...

Comment: Remove "touch_point = [touch locationInView:self.view];". And add in "for (UIImageView *image in piece_images) { ... }": "touch_point = [touch locationInView:image];". That does the trick :)!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sounds to me like the problem is you need to convert coordinates from your view's coordinates to the `UIImageView`'s coordinates. You can use `UIView`'s `convertPoint` method.

Try replacing

```
if ([image pointInside:touch_point withEvent:event]) {
```

with

```
if ([image pointInside: [self.view convertPoint:touch_point toView: image] withEvent:event]) {
```

(Note that you are allowed to pass `nil` instead of `event`.)

I guess this is a bit late for the questioner, but I hope it is of use to someone.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ([image pointInside:touch_point withEvent:event]) {
    // Point inside
}else {
    // Point isn't inside
}
```

In this case **event** is taken from :

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
```

Comment: You can pass `nil` to `event` when invoked programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{ 
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:self.view];

    for (UIImageView *piece in piece_images) {
        CGFloat x_min = piece.center.x - (piece.bounds.size.width / 2);
        CGFloat x_max = x_min + piece.bounds.size.width;
        CGFloat y_min = piece.center.y - (piece.bounds.size.height / 2);
        CGFloat y_max = y_min + piece.bounds.size.height;
        if (point.x > x_min && point.x < x_max && point.y > y_min && point.y < y_max ) {
            piece.hidden = YES;
        } else {
            piece.hidden = NO;
        }
    }

}
```

too bad, I have do it myself...

it's OS 3.2, XCode 3.2.2, tried both on simulator and iPad

Comment: I was just about to write this but i see you figured it out yourself. I think this is the best way to do it.