# Create custom button shape Swift 4

Tags: swift, xcode, uibutton, swift4, uibezierpath

I am creating an app that will require users to, among other things, tap to select areas on a diagram of the human body segmented into regions [(a similar example is shown here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PeXzr.jpg). To do so, I need to create buttons that will occasionally not fit the rectangular format provided by Xcode. The problem is similar or identical to that described in the following threads:

[Custom shape touchable area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32943735/custom-shape-touchable-area)

[Create clickable body diagram with Swift (iOS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36102099/create-clickable-body-diagram-with-swift-ios) (I found a bezier path tutorial and was able to create a path that would be great as an approximate button, if only I knew how to make it selectable and result in an action!)

[How to know that if the only visible area of a .png is touched in XCode (swift or objective C)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27923232/how-to-know-that-if-the-only-visible-area-of-a-png-is-touched-in-xcode-swift-o)

Unfortunately, I have been unable to implement the answers described above in storyboard mode (apologies if this is the incorrect term – I am very new to coding). My goal is simply to be able to overlay these buttons on the correct areas of the body, such that when clicked, the selected area is tinted a different color. I have also found several more solutions that are either coded for swift 2/3, or have resulted in mysterious SIGABRTs. Again, this answer may be just a clarification on how to implement any of the solutions above, I am honestly just new enough to swift that, after a weekend of trying, I am still unable to correctly apply these solutions in my own code.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you so much for any responses!

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, It depends on what kind of design you have. If you draw your body part in your code [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46990008/1835827) solution may help you. Basically, you define a bezier path and check if the path contains touch location. If you use images to draw body parts, you may check [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3ncPjqR6CAA). Basically you check if the color of touch area is a reference color or not. 
If you found another solution, it's better to share with us.

Also you can check my other solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52920166/1835827).