# Swift: Location on image filtering out certain parts of the image

Tags: swift, image, uiimageview, core-image, uitapgesturerecognizer

I want to have a pop up that records where you have pain on your abdomen (much like myIDB app. So the popup has the image of the body and you tap on there. A red marker shows your selection and you cannot place a mark outside the body. How can I set a filter to not allow input outside an image section?

[image]

Comment: Any tips at all of where to even look for an answer?

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer: [Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27923457/4153233) Where you get the alpha value of touch location. I will save the image with a transparent area outside where I want to touch and then its quite simple to determine if the area I want is touched.