# How to ignore pan gestures on transparent parts of UIImageViews?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, uikit, uigesturerecognizer

I want to use a pan gesture on visible UIImageViews's UIImage But this functionality is not implementing in objective c.

I have a UIImageView with P - Shaped and i have a UIView as it is sub view of p-shaped imageview. Now i want to move this view over the p-shaped imageview (It should not move outside the p-shaped).

Can anyone will help to achieve this functionality in objective c.

Comment: you can calculate actual non-transparent part size of image and then give that size to uiiimageView that also can solve your problem

Comment: No. i want to move the object with in non-transparent image(p -shaped)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27923232/how-to-know-that-if-the-only-visible-area-of-a-png-is-touched-in-xcode-swift-o

Comment: please check this also

Comment: @JagveerSingh .. Could you please give me more help as above link is not matching as per my requirement.

I want to move object( using Pan Gesture) around a p-shaped (p shaped can be make by using Bezire path or image) But there is an issue while moving the object. Sometime it crossing the boundary that's WRONG.
Could you tell me how to solve the problem.

Comment: you can set boundry of pan gesture moving area

Comment: @JagveerSingh .. But the moving area is in P shaped. Could you please help how can i do..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123155/discussion-between-sureshjangid-and-jagveer-singh).